# Android plugin for making a phone call by clicking a button in unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I want to make an android plugin for making a phone call by clicking on a button made in unity. How can I do this? Can anyone provide sample code?

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
Application.OpenURL( "tel://5555551212" )
```

Reference: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/button-to-make-phone-call.96227/